# javascript : how to get 'utc date' 

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a date in this string format "02/28/2012" and I want to convert it to UTC. 
I'm using the jquery datepicker to select thedate and populate an inputbox. any clues?
Thanks

Comment: UTC stands for `Universal TIME, Coordinated`. With that in mind, I'm not sure if asking for a date value in UTC makes any sense...

Comment: when you mean asking do you mean asking the user or the code or the datepicker? I'm looking to obtain a format like this one http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var datestr = "07/08/2005";
var datearr = datestr.split("/")
var utc = Date.UTC(datearr[2],datearr[0],datearr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var utcdate = Date.UTC(2012,2,28);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but they will give you the wrong result.

In Javascript, the month argument is zero-indexed, so make sure to subtract 1 from the standard month number,

```
var utcms = Date.UTC(2012,2-1,28);
```

Unfortunately jquery .datepicker.parseDate(str) injects a local timezone (it would be nice if the documentation said this), and Date(str) and Date.parse(str) appear unpredictable about their treatment of local vs UTC.